# Restart unresponsive phone without power button

Tags: adb, huawei

My huawei y9 prime became unresponsive and i cant connect it to my pc to reboot it with adb since i cannot press "use usb to transfer files" so adb doesnt see my device and as title says, power button is broken.
Can i force connect it using SN?
edit: forgot to say that phone was unlocked when it froze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update : only solutions i found is to either try to use a microusb mouse or to wait till phone is dead, download `fastboot` plug phone into pc, boot into fastboot mode (on huawei long press down volume key) till you get a screen, then enter command `fastboot devices` , if you see a number then use `fastboot reboot`